# React-router проблема browserHistory

Tags: node.js, веб-программирование, ruby-on-rails

Есть приложение на react в нем использую react router.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
  , document.getElementById('app')
);
```

когда работаю в webpack-dev-server все отлично включена опция historyApiFallback, когда тот же код открываю через сервер puma на rails 5 роутер работает если уже была загружена страница index.html. Если заходить на http://site.heroku.com/about выдает ошибку 404 как это побороть?

Comment: видимо надо добавить в about.html теже js-ы что и на index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Проблема

Про путь `/about` знает только твой клиентский javascript, но не сервер. К примеру:

- бразуер говорит `GET /`, сервер отдаёт `index.html` с кодом рутера;
- ты кликаешь на ссылку `/about`, рутер рендерит компонент и меняет `window.location`;
- ты обновляешь страницу;
- браузер говорит `GET /about`, сервер отвечает 404.

### Решение

Отдавать один и тот же html (`index.html`?) с сервера на любой<sup>1</sup> GET запрос. Не зная происходящего на сервере точнее, дать более конкретную рекомендацию не могу.

(Документация на английском для Node.js — https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/11-productionish-server.)

<sub><sup>1</sup> с умом конечно, чтобы случайно вместо favicon или скрипта не скормить браузеру html.</sub>